# How can I keep my "Documents" directory on another disk partition?

Tags: file-management, disk-management

I'm trying to point the path to my Home directory to a folder located on another hard drive which is a ntfs partition where all my Windows documents are. I think this is the path to 'Documents':

```
/media/charles/4ACE6B6ACE6B4D6F/Users/Charles/Documents
```

So I modified the path in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/media/charles/4ACE6B6ACE6B4D6F/Users/Charles/Documents"
```

After reboot it did not work; it was the same path as before. I tried to remove HOME like this:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/charles/4ACE6B6ACE6B4D6F/Users/Charles/Documents"
```

Also it did not work!

Is it because during the boot process elementary OS cannot mount this particular partition, so the OS cannot find the path in `user-dirs.dirs`? 
Or where else could be an error? In Ubuntu I use 'ubuntu tweak' for that purpose.

[image: gparted, user-dirs, path to ntfs documents]

Comment: Non of these solutions work...

Comment: I have an idea what is wrong with my answer, I'm going to add some information tomorrow.

Comment: hi, any solution for this purpose? thank you

Answer (score 4):

After modifying `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` you have to run

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

for the changes to take effect. If this doesn't work for you, try

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOCUMENTS /media/charles/4ACE6B6ACE6B4D6F/Users/Charles/Documents
```

to explicitly set the documents folder to your desired path.

Answer (score 0):

User dirs must be in your home directory. In your case, it is best to make a symbolic link.

- Give default `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documenten"` in the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`;
- Remove `~/Documenten` folder, if it exists;
- Create symlink with the following command:

  `ln -s /media/charles/4ACE6B6ACE6B4D6F/Users/Charles/Documents ~/Documenten`

Comment: not necessarily